# Surface Pro 4 Microsoft

Tags: microsoft-surface

I got a SP4 (Surface Pro 4) for Christmas and all was working perfect, but then I turned it on one day, swiped up and then went to put in my pin but when I typed using the keyboard, nothing appeared. Then I tried typing in my pin with the screen and nothing appeared! So in other words I can't type in my pin I have created. I have tried disconnecting the keyboard, holding down the on Button to refresh and it's not working. So now I can't even go into my laptop! Please help me.

Comment: There really isn't much information here for people to go on.

Comment: What do you mean??

Comment: @Rb123 - It means your question is not clear.  I am specifically confused on what you mean by "nothing appears".  What screen are you stuck at specifically?

Comment: The screen that appears when I turn on my surface. Where you have to swipe up and type in your pin. When I go to type in my pin no numbers are appearing in the box to login to my laptop

Comment: Your problem could be a manufacturing defect/failure in the keyboard, interface, or SP4, OS corruption, malware, a software problem, a configuration setting that got changed, an update that messed things up, etc.  All we know is a symptom.  Troubleshooting questions are hard to help with in this site's Q&A format.  Instead of a question with a factual answer, it's an open-ended series of "what do I try next" questions, or guesses, and the site isn't designed for that.  Since you just got it, the best solution may be to exchange it for a new one or have the store techs diagnose it.

Comment: @fixer1234 it would be worth mentioning that we can still diagnose problems via [chat] and then bring diagnostics back into the question to say what was tried and what didn't work. As OP is below 20 rep the room would need to be created by selecting the "let's take this to chat" comment message or by a mod migrating the comments to chat but it does work within the framework of the site *and* allows for better help. While remote faultfinding is difficult there are some steps you can go through with people.

Comment: @Mokubai: Wasn't aware that the "let's take this to chat" worked with <20 rep.  Good to know.  Thanks.

Comment: I *thought* it did, but I can't find a reference on it. If nothing else a mod can migrate a comment thread which will explicitly give OP write access to the room.

Answer (score 1):

The best option would be to try to remove the keyboard and use the touch screen based keyboard to type the pin - invoke it by tapping on icon:
[image]

If that works, connect the external keyboard and see if you can type in the cortana search. If it doesn't work, you may want to try to restore your OS and if even that fails take it back for a replacement.

Comment: The touch screen won't work either it is as if the numbers are invisible

Comment: Do you see "a response" from the touch screen? if yes i.e. the numbers show press, make sure the PIN box is in the focus - i.e. click with your finger inside the box where the **** for your PIN will appear

Comment: When I touch the numbers it's like I pressed it but no numbers are appearing and when I press enter it says please enter a pin